# How to import a single column of data into a mysql table

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Using MySQL 'Load Data Infile' in a windows environment, I found that the data that was uploaded is truncated.  The first 2 characters were removed, but I am not sure why.

The data file looks like this:

```
ABL1
AKT1
AKT2
AKT3
ALK
ALOX12B
...
```

The uploaded data looks like:

```
|L1
|T1
|T2
|T3
|K
|OX12B
...
```

The sql command is:

```
load data infile "C:\\Users\\jw708\\Documents\\scripts\\perl\\OncoPanel_v1_exonic.csv" 
into table loadPanelGenes 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

I was expecting the data to load correctly.

Comment: If the CSV file was created on Windows, you should use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. And why do you need `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` when there's only one field?

Comment: Originally there were 2 columns; you're right, I can remove the fields clause.